# Custom geometry registered in A-Frame isn't rendering when added to a scene

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, aframe, webvr

I've created some functions that create THREE.js geometries with phi length values under 360 that are non-hollow, and I would like to render them in an A-Frame scene (which is running on top of React). However, when I try to render them, I find that I can't.

I thought my custom geometry wasn't registering, but I rendered a copy of the box geometry outlined [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/geometry.html#register-a-custom-geometry) with no problems.

This is my code I used to register the custom geometry:

```
this.AFRAME.registerGeometry("phisphere", {
    schema : {
        phi : { default : 360, min : 0, type : "int" },
    },    
    init : (data) => {
        let phi = this.degToRad(data.phi);
        let sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 18, 36, 0, phi);

        let semiStart = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 36, 0, Math.PI);
        semiStart.applyMatrix(this.rotationMatrix("z", Math.PI / 2));
        semiStart.applyMatrix(this.rotationMatrix("x", Math.PI));

        let semiEnd = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 32, 0, Math.PI);
        semiEnd.applyMatrix(this.rotationMatrix("z", Math.PI / 2));
        semiEnd.applyMatrix(this.rotationMatrix("y", phi));

        let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.merge(sphere);
        geometry.merge(semiStart);
        geometry.merge(semiEnd);

        this.geometry = geometry;
    }
});
```

and this is the call I'm using to render it:

```html
<a-entity geometry="primitive: phisphere; phi : 260" scale="2 2 2" position="0 2 0"></a-entity>
```

Nothing's showing up. I'm not sure where I went wrong here, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that will bind the methods to the wrong `this`. Use regular functions instead:

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry("phisphere", {
  schema : {phi : {default : 360, min : 0, type : "int"}},    
  init : function () {}
});
```

Working example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fanatical-cardamom?path=phisphere.js:5:19